# How to convert hex to ASCII characters in the Linux shell?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, encoding, scripting

Let's say that I have a string `5a`.

This is the hex representation of the ASCII letter `Z`.

I need to find a Linux shell command which will take a hex string and output the ASCII characters that the hex string represents.

So if I do:

```
echo 5a | command_im_looking_for
```

I will see a solitary letter `Z`:

```
Z
```

Answer (score 63, accepted):

```
echo -n 5a | perl -pe 's/([0-9a-f]{2})/chr hex $1/gie'
```

Note that this won't skip non-hex characters. If you want just the hex (no whitespace from the original string etc):

```
echo 5a | perl -ne 's/([0-9a-f]{2})/print chr hex $1/gie'
```

Also, `zsh` and `bash` support this natively in `echo`:

```
echo -e '\x5a'
```

Comment: You probably need to put an "i" after the regexes there.

Comment: Or put a-fA-F in the character class.

Comment: I'm not normally a fan of perl, but this is the sort of stuff that it does well.  If you're going to be converting a very large amount of data, though, it would be better to write a short C program to do this.

Comment: I don't think you will see much benefit from doing it in C until you have to deal with terabytes of data.

Comment: @Kinopiko, it processes about 1.5 MB/s (output) here, so really, by the time you get to hundreds of megabytes, it's time to write something in a faster language :)

Comment: Much easier to use `perl -lne 'print pack "H*", $_'`.

Comment: @Randal, it's easier for me to use this one because I don't need to `perldoc -f pack` each time ;) of course, YMMV...

Comment: `echo -ne '\x5a'` is necessary, given the example: without the -n switch for echo, a new line ('\x0a') will be output after the Z.

Comment: as a side note to what @antik said, one could test if everything's right via `echo -ne '\x5a\xde\x0b\x0d' | xxd`

Comment: I had a huge hex string generated from a mysqldump hex-blob saved to a variable. I used a modified form of the above to output the original file. I used `echo -e "$(echo $hex | sed 's_\(..\)_\\x\1_g')"`. Just saw the next post using `xxd`. `echo $hex | xxd -r -p` worked like a charm.

Answer (score 117):

I used to do this with [xxd](https://linux.die.net/man/1/xxd):

```
echo -n 5a | xxd -r -p
```

But then I realised that in Debian/Ubuntu, xxd is part of vim-common and hence might not be present in a minimal system. To also avoid Perl (IMHO also not part of a minimal system), I ended up using sed, xargs, and printf like this:

```
echo -n 5a | sed 's/\([0-9A-F]\{2\}\)/\\\\\\x\1/gI' | xargs printf
```

Mostly, I only want to convert a few bytes and it's okay for such tasks. The advantage of this solution over [the one of ghostdog74](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1604765/how-to-convert-hex-to-ascii-characters-in-the-linux-shell#1604890) is, that this can convert hex strings of arbitrary lengths automatically. xargs is used because printf doesnt read from standard input.

Comment: Damn, i know it's 3 years later on the orignial answer, but I had no clue xxd existed.  With the issue i'm having now, i have continual need for it... constant hex dumps of byte strings from a debugger.  And yeah, @Vouze comment is damn pointless.

Comment: Instead of `"echo -n 5a | xxd -r -p"` I'd prefer to use `"xxd -r -p <<< 5a"`. **Advantages:** ***(1)*** a few less characters to type (typing also faster because of 3x repetition); ***(2)*** runs only *one* command (saves the `echo`), not *two* => faster execution.

Comment: @KurtPfeifle `sh: 1: Syntax error: redirection unexpected` disadvantage: not POSIX

Comment: @josch: Sorry, I should have mentioned it needs Bash to work. It is a `here string` in Bash (a concept similar to a `here document`).

Comment: xxd -r not available in busybox, but the second one is fine. thanks

Answer (score 16):

You can do this with `echo` only, without the other stuff. Don't forget to add "-n" or you will get a linebreak automatically:

```
echo -n -e "\x5a"
```

Comment: Doesn't answer the question asked above, but answers the question I was searching for when google send me here :-) (btw. sending the output to | hexdump -C helps to identify unwanted newlines etc.)

Comment: This requires that `\x` be inserted before each hex pair. Example was `5a`, but question was about converting a hex string to multiple ASCII characters.

Answer (score 10):

Bash one-liner

```
echo -n "5a" | while read -N2 code; do printf "\x$code"; done
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for multi-byte messages... When I run 
`echo -n "0102abcd" | while read -n 2 code; do printf "\x$code"; done | hexdump`

yields

`0201 cdab`

Comment: @John Steel It seems hexdump displays data as numeric words in hex by default. Try this `echo -n "0102abcd" | while read -n 2 code; do printf "\x$code"; done | hexdump -e '/1 "%02x"'`

Answer (score 5):

Some Python 3 one-liners that work with any number of bytes.

## Decoding hex

Using `strip`, so that it's ok to have a newline on stdin.

```
$ echo 666f6f0a | python3 -c "import sys, binascii; sys.stdout.buffer.write(binascii.unhexlify(input().strip()))"
foo
```

## Encoding hex

```
$ echo foo | python3 -c "import sys, binascii; print(binascii.hexlify(sys.stdin.buffer.read()).decode())"
666f6f0a
```

Comment: Just use print when decoding hex and you can see ctrl chars, null chars, e.t.c.. e.g. 'echo 666f6f0a62617200 | python3 -c "import sys, binascii; print(binascii.unhexlify(input()))"' OUTPUT:
'b'foo\nbar\x00''

Comment: You can shorten this to: `python3 -c 'import binascii; print(binascii.unhexlify(input()))' <<< 486921`

Answer (score 4):

Depending on where you got that "5a", you can just prepend "\x" to it and pass that to `printf`:

```
$ a=5a
$ a="\x${a}"
$ printf "$a"
Z
```

Comment: The second and third lines can be collapsed into one: `printf "\x${a}"`

Answer (score 2):

```
echo 5a | python -c "import sys; print chr(int(sys.stdin.read(),base=16))"
```

Comment: Change the `print` to `sys.stdout.write` to prevent the extra linefeed character.

Comment: `OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long`

Answer (score 2):

Here is a pure bash script (as printf is a bash builtin) :

```
#warning : spaces do matter
die(){ echo "$@" >&2;exit 1;}

p=48656c6c6f0a

test $((${#p} & 1)) == 0 || die "length is odd"
p2=''; for ((i=0; i<${#p}; i+=2));do p2=$p2\\x${p:$i:2};done
printf "$p2"
```

If bash is already running, this should be faster than any other solution which is launching a new process.

Comment: slightly shorter: `for ((i=0; i<${#p}; i+=2));do p2+=\\x${p:$i:2};done`

Answer (score 2):

dc can convert between numeric bases:

```
$ echo 5a | (echo 16i; tr 'a-z' 'A-Z'; echo P) | dc
Z$
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a simple shell command [`ascii`](http://www.catb.org/%7Eesr/ascii/).

If you use Ubuntu, install it with:

```
sudo apt install ascii
```

Then

```
ascii 0x5a
```

will output:

```
ASCII 5/10 is decimal 090, hex 5a, octal 132, bits 01011010: prints as `Z'
Official name: Majuscule Z
Other names: Capital Z, Uppercase Z
```

Answer (score 1):

As per [@Randal comment](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22483/randal-schwartz), you can use `perl`, e.g.

```
$ printf 5a5a5a5a | perl -lne 'print pack "H*", $_'
ZZZZ
```

and other way round:

```
$ printf ZZZZ | perl -lne 'print unpack "H*", $_'
5a5a5a5a
```

---

Another example with file:

```
$ printf 5a5a5a5a | perl -lne 'print pack "H*", $_' > file.bin
$ perl -lne 'print unpack "H*", $_' < file.bin
5a5a5a5a
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this command (python script) for larger inputs:

```
echo 58595a | python -c "import sys; import binascii; print(binascii.unhexlify(sys.stdin.read().strip()).decode())"
```

The result will be:

```
XYZ
```

And for more simplicity, define an alias:

```
alias hexdecoder='python -c "import sys; import binascii; print(binascii.unhexlify(sys.stdin.read().strip()).decode())"'

echo 58595a | hexdecoder
```

Answer (score 0):

GNU awk 4.1

```
awk -niord '$0=chr("0x"RT)' RS=.. ORS=
```

Note that if you echo to this it will produce an extra null byte

```
$ echo 595a | awk -niord '$0=chr("0x"RT)' RS=.. ORS= | od -tx1c
0000000  59  5a  00
          Y   Z  \0
```

Instead use printf

```
$ printf 595a | awk -niord '$0=chr("0x"RT)' RS=.. ORS= | od -tx1c
0000000  59  5a
          Y   Z
```

Also note that GNU awk produces UTF-8 by default

```
$ printf a1 | awk -niord '$0=chr("0x"RT)' RS=.. ORS= | od -tx1
0000000 c2 a1
```

If you are dealing with characters outside of ASCII, and you are going to be
Base64 encoding the resultant string, you can disable UTF-8 with `-b`

```
echo 5a | sha256sum | awk -bniord 'RT~/\w/,$0=chr("0x"RT)' RS=.. ORS=
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to my answer here: [Linux shell scripting: hex number to binary string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605927/linux-shell-scripting-hex-number-to-binary-string/47253189#47253189)

You can do it with the same tool like this (using ascii printable character instead of `5a`):

```
echo -n 616263 | cryptocli dd -decoders hex
```

Will produce the following result:

```
abcd
```