# Linux shell scripting: hex number to binary string

Tags: linux, shell, hex

I am looking for some easy way in shell script for converting hex number into sequence of 0 and 1 characters.

Example:

```
5F -> "01011111"
```

Is there any command or easy method for accomplish it or should I write some switch for it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I used 'bc' command in Linux. (much more complex calculator than converting!)

> echo 'ibase=16;obase=2;5f' | bc

ibase parameter is the input base (hexa in this case), and obase the output base  (binary).

Hope it helps.

Comment: Set `obase` before `ibase`. If `ibase` is defined first, `bc` will try to interpret `obase` as if it is written in `ibase`, with possibly erroneous results. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9889839/bc-and-its-ibase-obase-options).

Comment: Using`bc` version 1.06.95 `echo 'ibase=16;obase=2;5f' | bc` produces error: `(standard_in) 1: syntax error`. However, `echo 'ibase=16;obase=2;5F' | bc` works and produces `1011111`.

Answer (score 12):

```
echo "ibase=16; obase=2; 5F" | bc
```

Comment: Thanks, it is the same as my selected correct answer, I've chosen it since there is explanation

Comment: This is not the same as the selected answer. This has `5F`, whereas the selected answer has `5f`. This answer works in `bc` 1.06.95, wheras the selected answer does not.

Answer (score 8):

```
$ printf '\x5F' | xxd -b | cut -d' ' -f2
01011111
```

Or

```
$ dc -e '16i2o5Fp'
1011111
```

- The **`i`** command will pop the top of the stack and use it for the input base.
- **`Hex`** digits must be in upper case to avoid collisions with dc commands and are not limited to **`A-F`** if the input radix is larger than `16`.
- The **`o`** command does the same for the output base.
- The **`p`** command will print the top of the stack with a newline after it.

Comment: Thanks for response, it's great to have so many ways of achieving this task :) I've chosen the "bc" variant

Answer (score 2):

Perl’s `printf` already knows binary:

```
$ perl -e 'printf "%08b\n", 0x5D'
01011101
```

Answer (score 1):

I wrote https://github.com/tehmoon/cryptocli for those kind of jobs.

Here's an example:

```
echo -n 5f5f5f5f5f | cryptocli dd -decoders hex -encoders binary_string
```

Yields:

```
0101111101011111010111110101111101011111
```

The opposite also works.

NB: It's not perfect and much work needs to be done but it is working.