# bc and its ibase/obase options:

Tags: radix, bc

I stumbled over a curious bug, I think:

I tried to read "512" as a number to base 6, and output it as base 16:

```
echo "ibase=6;obase=16;512" | bc
161
```

As you can see, the output is 161, but it should be `bc`(sic!). I tried with base 10:

```
echo "ibase=6;obase=10;512" | bc
512
```

The value is unchanged. Curious! Default obase is 10. If I omit it:

```
echo "ibase=6;512" | bc
188
```

Well, that seems right. In a two step process, it works:

```
echo "obase=16;"$(echo "ibase=6;512" | bc) | bc
BC
```

So I made a script for different bases, but it keeps me puzzled:

```
for ib in {6,8,10,16}; do echo $ib; for ob in {10,16}; do echo -en $ib $ob"     \t => " ; echo "ibase=$ib;obase=$ob;333" | bc ; done; done; 
6
6 10         => 333
6 16         => 108
8
8 10         => 333
8 16         => 119
10
10 10        => 333
10 16        => 14D
16
16 10        => 333
16 16        =>  01 15 05
```

Shall I file a bugreport, or do I miss the obvious? I can't really believe that such a basic tool is broken.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Not a bug.

As soon as `ibase=6` is interpreted, numbers are read in base 6. So `ibase=6;obase=16` makes obase's value to be 16<sub>base 6</sub> which is invalid, and is interpreted as 11<sub>decimal</sub>.

From the man page:

> For multi-digit numbers, bc changes all input digits greater or equal to ibase to the value of ibase-1.

So 16 is interpreted as 15<sub>base 6</sub> which is 11<sub>decimal</sub>. And the conversion is correct.

Set `obase` before `ibase`, or make sure to specify your obase in base `ibase`.

```
$ echo "obase=16;ibase=6;512" | bc
BC
```

Answer (score 5):

See http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/unix/upt/ch49_03.htm

When you set `ibase` or `obase`, it's expressed with the current base of `ibase`. So set `obase` before you set `ibase` if you want to express `obase` in decimal.

See also http://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/html_mono/bc.html#SEC9

> Input numbers may contain the characters 0-9 and A-F. (Note: They must be capitals. Lower case letters are variable names.) Single digit numbers always have the value of the digit regardless of the value of ibase. (i.e. A = 10.) **For multi-digit numbers, bc changes all input digits greater or equal to ibase to the value of ibase-1.** This makes the number FFF always be the largest 3 digit number of the input base.

So for `obase=16` in `ibase=6`, the `6` becomes a `5`, and it is equivalent to an output base of decimal `6 * 1 + 1 * 5 == 11`, thus:

```
$ echo "obase=11;ibase=6;512" | bc
161
```

Answer (score 0):

Slightly modify the code (two ways) and your expected results appear:

```
for ib in {6,8,10,16}; do 
    echo $ib; for ob in {10,16}; do 
        echo -en $ib $ob"     \t => " ; 
        ob=`echo "obase=$ib;$ob" | bc`
        echo "ibase=$ib;obase=$ob;333" | bc ; 
    done; 
done;

for ib in {6,8,10,16}; do 
    echo $ib; for ob in {10,16}; do 
        echo -en $ib $ob"     \t => " ; 
        echo "obase=$ob;ibase=$ib;333" | bc ; 
    done; 
done;
```

[execute in bash sandbox](http://%20http://tpcg.io/whagAB)

results for both ways are:

```
6
6 10         => 129
6 16         => 81
8
8 10         => 219
8 16         => DB
10
10 10        => 333
10 16        => 14D
16
16 10        => 819
16 16        => 333
```