# bc command acts strange on obase=10

Tags: linux, bc

today i found the 'bc' linux command and found a strange behaviour when calculating with outputbase 10.

```
echo "ibase=16;obase=9;AFBE" | bc
67638

echo "ibase=16;obase=11;AFBE" | bc
09 02 11 08

echo "ibase=16;obase=10;AFBE" | bc
AFBE
```

well, command 1 and 2 are correct, but the third command simply prints the inputvalue.

```
echo "ibase=16;AFBE" | bc
44990
```

gives a correct result.

Is there any reason in this behaviour?

Comment: possible duplicate of [bc and it's ibase/obase options:](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9889839/bc-and-its-ibase-obase-options)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not the [first person to be caught by this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9889839/bc-and-its-ibase-obase-options).
Apparently you need to set `obase` **before** `ibase`:

```
echo "obase=10;ibase=16;AFBE" | bc
44990
```

Answer (score 2):

Obviously, `bc` uses your `ibase` when it reads `obase`: that's why `obase=10` always means "the same as `ibase`".

In the latest example, you don't give `obase=10` (which would set the value to decimal 16), that's why `obase` remains the default (decimal 10).