# Hex to Binary conversion in bash

Tags: bash, binary, hex, bc

I'm trying to convert a series of bytes from hex to bin using bash.
but I keep getting (seemingly random) "(standard_in) 1: syntax error" replies from the following code:

```
for j in c4 97 91 8c 85 87 c4 90 8c 8d 9a 83 81
do
        BIN=$(echo "obase=2; ibase=16; $j" | bc )
        echo $BIN
done
```

I did a similar thing with dec to bin, which works perfectly fine:

```
for i in {0..120}
do
        KEYBIN=$(echo "obase=2; ibase=10; $i" | bc)
        echo $KEYBIN
done
```

Does anyone have an idea why it works with decimal, but not with hex?
In my opinion the syntax is pretty much the same (unless I'm missing something really hard.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [linux shell scripting: hex string to bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1604765/linux-shell-scripting-hex-string-to-bytes)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

BC is a bit sensitive to case for hex values, change to uppercase and it should work

```
for j in C4 97 91 8C 85 87 C4 90 8C 8D 9A 83 81
do
        BIN=$(echo "obase=2; ibase=16; $j" | bc )
        echo $BIN
done
```

Output:

```
11000100
10010111
10010001
10001100
10000101
10000111
11000100
10010000
10001100
10001101
10011010
10000011
10000001
```

Comment: so it really was a simple error. thank you for pointing this out, works like a charm.

Comment: glad to help, BC is a great tool with some quirks that you just have to know :-)

Comment: Does anybody know how to pad bc's output to a certain number of digits? This isn't needed in the example above, but just try the loop with a 00 as input.

Comment: have a look at the `length` function. "The value of the length function is the number of significant digits in the expression."

Comment: Here is an example with just one value:
`echo "obase=2; ibase=16; EF" | bc`

Answer (score 17):

I came up with this:

printf converts to hex, xxd -r -p takes the ascii hex stream and makes it actual binary

dumping with hexdump to prove it worked...

```
printf "%016x" 53687091200 | xxd -r -p | hexdump -C
```

Comment: Works. However, `xxd` won't let me combine `-r` and `-p` into `-rp`, and I can live with that for now.

Comment: how very un-unix like, but it is what it is I guess. you could open an issue on github probably :-)

Comment: the answer is amazing

Answer (score 7):

Here's the script I use:

```
#!/bin/bash
# SCRIPT:  hex2binary.sh
# USAGE:   hex2binary.sh Hex_Number(s)
# PURPOSE: Hex to Binary Conversion. Takes input as command line
#          arguments.
#####################################################################
#                      Script Starts Here                           #
#####################################################################

if [ $# -eq 0 ]
then
    echo "Argument(s) not supplied "
    echo "Usage: hex2binary.sh hex_number(s)"
else
    echo -e "\033[1mHEX                 \t\t BINARY\033[0m"

    while [ $# -ne 0 ]
    do
        DecNum=`printf "%d" $1`
        Binary=
        Number=$DecNum

        while [ $DecNum -ne 0 ]
        do
            Bit=$(expr $DecNum % 2)
            Binary=$Bit$Binary
            DecNum=$(expr $DecNum / 2)
        done

        echo -e "$Number              \t\t $Binary"
        shift
        # Shifts command line arguments one step.Now $1 holds second argument
        unset Binary
    done

fi
```

Comment: Caveats: The hex numbers must be preceded by `0x`, and the **HEX** column actually lists decimal values. But thank you for offering a pure bash solution to a "How to ... in bash" question! Sometimes that's actually what people are looking for. You can't always depend on the presence of tools like bc.

Comment: the version of bash I am using (`4.4.12`) doesn't need to prefix the hex numbers. The script doesn't handle `0` correctly though, you want to replace `$Binary` with `${Binary:-0}` in the last `echo` call

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```sh
for j in c4 97 91 8c 85 87 c4 90 8c 8d 9a 83 81
do
    BIN=$(echo "obase=2; ibase=16; ${j^^}" | bc )
    echo $BIN
done
```

Comment: There are other answers that provide the OP's question, and they were posted some time ago. When posting an answer [see: How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), please make sure you add either a new solution, or a substantially better explanation, especially when answering older questions.

Comment: Accepted answer says uppercase is required and changes the input data. This answer keeps the data (that often is out of control) and instead uses `${j^^}` to convert the data to uppercase, thus this is the better solution, but lacking in explanation.