# Inverting a binary number in Bash

Tags: linux, bash, reverse, tr

I am trying to invert an 8 bit Binary number using bash and shell script making 1 0 and vice versa then save the new variable, turning 10101010 into 01010101.

```
input=10101010
echo $input 
echo $Input | tr 01 10
```

will give me

```
10101010
01010101
```

but does not allow me to save this to a new variable if i try:

```
invertedInput=$Input | tr 01 10
```

How can I get this right?

Comment: backticks... check process interpolation.

Comment: or $()
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9449778/what-is-the-benefit-of-using-instead-of-backticks-in-shell-scripts

Comment: question : do you want this to work on 'binary' numbers, the answer below does not work for
00111001
11000110

Comment: I think you would have to use "bc" to work on binary number and apply   [hexnumber] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40667382/how-to-perform-bitwise-operations-on-hexadecimal-numbers-in-bash)   [convertion hex] (   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11120324/hex-to-binary-conversion-in-bash)

Answer (score 2):

Use `x=$(cmd)` to capture the output of a command and assign it to a variable.

In addition, as a good practice, use `cmd <<< ...` instead of `echo ... | cmd` when passing the content of a variable to the standard input of a command.

Like this:

```
input=10101010
invertedInput=$(tr 01 10 <<< "$input")
echo "$invertedInput"
# prints: 01010101
```

Comment: Why do you consider Here String better practice than using echo?

Comment: @mjb2kmn `echo` is an extra process. Here String is a native feature. It's faster.

Comment: Although the pipeline with `echo` does induce a subshell/`clone`, the [here-string uses a temporary file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/219804/resource-usage-using-pipe-and-here-string) (unlinked after pipes are set-up). So the [speed actually depends](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/219806/232065) on the size of the data passed (along with fs setup, etc). In `bash`, *`tr <<< data` is usually faster for smaller chunks of data, and `echo data | tr` is faster for bigger chunks*.

Answer (score 2):

you just need to wrap the output of your expression with $( )

```
invertedInput=$(echo $input | tr 01 10)
```

echo $invertedInput

```
01010101
```